# Installing ImageMagick on Mac from source

Tags: imagemagick, osx-elcapitan

i am trying to install ImageMagick version 6.9.6-2 on MAC OSX 10.11.5
Following the steps below:

1) Install pkg-config. ( if you dont have it already installed )

Latest: https://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.29.1.tar.gz

What is currently installed on linux: pkg-config --version = 0.23
/usr/bin/pkg-config

The pkg-config program is used to retrieve information about installed libraries in the system. It is typically used to compile and link against one or more libraries.

2) Install libpng.
3) Install ghostscript, current version: GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)) , latest is 9.20
3) Then you can compile and install ImageMagick with the PNG reference library.

NOTE: As a pre-requisite, XCOde and commndline utils for xcode need to be installed

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.3.1/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.3.1.dmg

Making XCode and Command Line tools internally available @ : just download and install the dmg ( you need admin permissions on your mac)

XCODE : http://localnexus:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/com/osx/xcode/7.3.1/xcode-7.3.1.dmg

XCODE_CLI: http://localnexus:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/com/osx/xcode-comandline-tools/7.3.1/xcode-comandline-tools-7.3.1.dmg

Configure pkg-config:

curl -O http://localnexus:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/com/pkg-config/pkg-config/0.29.1/pkg-config-0.29.1.gz
tar xvfz pkg-config-0.29.1.gz
cd pkg-config-0.29.1
export LDFLAGS="-framework CoreFoundation -framework Carbon" 
./configure --with-internal-glib --prefix=/usr/local/pkgconfig
make && make check
sudo make install

export PATH="/usr/local/keyconfig/bin:$PATH"

Install libpng:

curl -O http://localnexus:8080/content/repositories/thirdparty/com/libpng/libpng/1.6.25/libpng-1.6.25.gz
tar zxf libpng-1.6.25.tar.gz
cd libpng-1.6.25
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/libpng/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/libpng/include"
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libpng
sudo make && make check
sudo make install

Link pkg-config
sudo ln -s /usr/local/pkgconfig/bin/pkg-config /usr/local/libpng/bin

sudo ln -s /usr/local/pkgconfig/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0-pkg-config /usr/local/libpng/bin

Install GhostScript: since its on Mac, we can either go by the dmg, or source code:

curl -O http://localnexus:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/com/ghostscript/mac/ghostscript/9.20/ghostscript-9.20.pkg

This package installs Ghostscript 9.20 in /usr/local. The package supports macOS 10.5, Snow Leopard, through macOS 10.12, Sierra on Intel processors. The package does not support PowerPC processors.

verify:
$ gs --version
9.20

install ImageMagick:

download ImageMagick-6.9.6-2 curl -O http://localnexus:8080/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/Imagemagick/6.9.6-2/Imagemagick-6.9.6-2.gz
tar xvfz Imagemagick-6.9.6-2.gz
cd ImageMagick-6.9.6-2
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/libpng/lib/"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/libpng/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/libpng/lib/pkgconfig/"
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/magick --with-jpeg --with-png --with-tiff --without-perl --with-bzlib=yes --with-freetype=yes --with-gslib=yes --with-magick-plus-plus=yes --with-zlib=yes --with-xml=yes 
make
sudo make install

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/magick/bin

but unable to add the delegates like jpeg, or add openMP in FEATURE. plus i am not sure how can i verify that ghostscript is installed and working WITH ImageMagick

here is the result of ./configure:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/lib' LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib' --enable-shared --enable-static --with-magick-plus-plus --with-wmf --with-gslib --with-rsvg --with-xml --enable-hdri --with-fftw=yes --with-gslib --enable-hdri --enable-openmp --with-modules --enable-delegate-build  --with-jpeg  --disable-dependency-tracking --with-tiff --with-gslib --with-hdf --with-jbig --with-dps --with-perl --with-fpx --with-x --with-zlib

ImageMagick is configured as follows. Please verify that this configuration
matches your expectations.

  Host system type: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
  Build system type: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0

                 Option                        Value
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Shared libraries  --enable-shared=yes     yes
  Static libraries  --enable-static=yes     yes
  Module support    --with-modules=yes      yes
  GNU ld            --with-gnu-ld=no        no
  Quantum depth     --with-quantum-depth=16 16
  High Dynamic Range Imagery
                    --enable-hdri=yes       yes

  Install documentation:            yes

  Delegate Library Configuration:
  BZLIB             --with-bzlib=yes        yes
  Autotrace         --with-autotrace=no     no
  DJVU              --with-djvu=yes     no
  DPS               --with-dps=yes      no
  FFTW              --with-fftw=yes     no
  FLIF              --with-flif=yes     no
  FlashPIX          --with-fpx=yes      no
  FontConfig        --with-fontconfig=yes   no
  FreeType          --with-freetype=yes     no
  Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=yes        no
  Graphviz          --with-gvc=yes      no
  JBIG              --with-jbig=yes     no
  JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yes     no
  LCMS              --with-lcms=yes     no
  LQR               --with-lqr=yes      no
  LTDL              --with-ltdl=yes     yes
  LZMA              --with-lzma=yes     no
  Magick++          --with-magick-plus-plus=yes yes
  OpenEXR           --with-openexr=yes      no
  OpenJP2           --with-openjp2=yes      no
  PANGO             --with-pango=yes        no
  PERL              --with-perl=yes     /usr/bin/perl
  PNG               --with-png=yes      no
  RAQM              --with-raqm=yes     no
  RSVG              --with-rsvg=yes     no
  TIFF              --with-tiff=yes     yes
  WEBP              --with-webp=yes     no
  WMF               --with-wmf=yes      no
  X11               --with-x=yes            no
  XML               --with-xml=yes      no
  ZLIB              --with-zlib=yes     no

  Delegate Program Configuration:
  GhostPCL          None                pcl6 (unknown)
  GhostXPS          None                gxps (unknown)
  Ghostscript       None                gs (9.20)

  Font Configuration:
  Apple fonts       --with-apple-font-dir=default
  Dejavu fonts      --with-dejavu-font-dir=default  none
  Ghostscript fonts --with-gs-font-dir=default  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/
  Windows fonts     --with-windows-font-dir=default none

  X11 Configuration:
        X_CFLAGS        =
        X_PRE_LIBS      =
        X_LIBS          =
        X_EXTRA_LIBS    =

  Options used to compile and link:
    PREFIX          = /usr/local
    EXEC-PREFIX     = /usr/local
    VERSION         = 6.9.6
    CC              = gcc
    CFLAGS          =   -g -O2 -Wall -mtune=haswell -fexceptions -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
    CPPFLAGS        =  -I/usr/local/lib -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/magick -I/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/tiff/libtiff -I/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/wand -I/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/zlib
    PCFLAGS         =
    DEFS            = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
    LDFLAGS         = -L/usr/local/lib -L/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/magick/.libs -L/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/magick -L/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/tiff/libtiff/.libs -L/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/tiff/libtiff -L/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/wand/.libs -L/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/wand -L/Users/skahmed/devops/TOOLS/IMAGEMAGICK/temp/ImageMagick-6.9.6-2/zlib
    LIBS            =
    CXX             = g++
    CXXFLAGS        = -g -O2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
    FEATURES        = DPC HDRI Cipher Modules
    DELEGATES       = bzlib mpeg ps tiff
========================================================================
```

convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.6-2 Q16 x86_64 2016-10-28 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI
Delegates (built-in): bzlib

Comment: Why would you do that when it is just `brew install imagemagick` with **homebrew**?

Comment: @Mark Setchell homebrew is not allowed within the network , hence i am left with the only option to using internal Nexus and compiling from source

Comment: I don't know what your question is. Ensure libjpeg is installed from [jpegsrc](http://www.ijg.org), and that you using [LLVM](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html) with separate [OpenMP plugin installed](https://clang-omp.github.io)  (not the compiler tool chain shipped by apple).

Comment: @emcconville question is: how can i install ImageMagick from source on Mac with any FEATURE and DELEGATE. As far as delegate jpeg is concerned, i followed your advice and was able to integrate it with ImageMagick. Not sure about openMP. I am guessing installing llvm and building openMP using llvm ? as for the last question, i would compile and integrate GhostScript.

Comment: @emcconville I cannot seem to get GhostScript work with ImageMagick. I have tried 9.16, 9.18 and 9.20 ( download , ./configure, make, sudo make install ) and then ./configure make, sudo make install ImageMagick 6.9.6-2, but i cannot get yes to : Delegate (Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=yes  no)